# JavaScript files validation are failing in Eclipse under Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, swagger, swagger-2.0

Maven project in eclipse (Mars) is of basic webapp type. JavaScript files (files for Swagger ui) present for this project are valid. There are no syntax issues with those. But when "update project" is done, it says all JavaScript files have some error even though those files are valid when checked outside.

Errors are as below:

> Syntax error on token ":", ( expected

etc.

I have tried:

1. cleaning up the project & updating the project.
2. removing the validation for java scripts in eclipse, but it throws error while loading those files.
3. having a new project but getting same issues.
4. removing .m2/repository & updating the project again.

None of the above trial worked.

JDK: 1.7 & Tomcat 8.0.53 are being used.

I guess there are some issues with the configuration at Eclipse or Maven level.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you mean *JavaScript* files, the dynamicly typed language that runs in the browser and Maven doesn't compile, or Java *source* files? Can you post a code example of what it says is a syntax error?

Comment: java script files. Errors are as below:
Syntax error on token ":", ( expected
Syntax error on token "}", ; expected
 etc.

Comment: Try to put screenshot of error msg, or try to figure out the file/line_number the error is pointing to. If it's your code only, then maybe some syntax issue. But the context you provided is too low to think of it.

Comment: These java script files are for swagger ui (https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/installation/ :  codes are already available, no need to change anything in that). When I am trying the same file on "https://esprima.org/demo/validate.html" for its validation, it's working fine.

Comment: If it's giving the error message `Syntax error on token ":", ( expected Syntax error on token "}", ;` then it shd also be mentioning the file location and line number, maybe from there you could get a hint abt the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project -> Validate : solved this problem.